# How to control lots of java thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Currently, I have a while loop for listening the port. When a socket accepta a connection, a Task, which implements a `runnable` interface will be created, and is assigned to the `LinkedList` named `o_allTaskThreads` to store it. That is to let me have control, to stop them.

```
                s = this.o_ServerSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("connection established");

                PortListenTask plt = new PortListenTask(s,this.o_config);
                this.o_allTaskThreads.add(plt);
                plt.run();
```

But I got some problems here, if the `PortListenTask` is done/finished or have exception terminaled, it can't update the linkedLIst `o_allTaskThreads`, how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you considered using Java executor framework - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html It provides thread pools and some other usefull stuff.

Comment: 't can't updated the linkedLIst o_allTaskThreads' - why not?  You should lok the list, iterate it to find the entry and remove it. You should take car if another thread/task might be accessing it at the time - set some inernal state to 'disconnected' and put it on a timer queue for eventual deletion of its last reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the PortListenTask's run() method ends (normal execution completes), can it not update the linked list (I assume to remove itself) then? If you add a try / catch handler around the contents of your run() method then hopefully you can trap abnormal situations and help guide them through the same clean exit. You should always try and *signal* a thread to exit itself, rather than abort them externally, to allow such a clean exit.

Comment: +1 for the 'normal' approach.  The list needs locking, but this should work.

Answer (score 2):

The `LinkedList` is not very good idea to store threads or jobs.
Try reading this [Thread pools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) and this [Thread pools and workers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730/index.html), that might help.

Comment: [Executors.newCachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) You have thread pool. When the thread is finished it comes back to pool.

Comment: you will store in LinkedList all the jobs. So there will be threads which are currently running and which are already terminated. That is not good according to paradigm of 'reusing resources'.
And LinkedList is not synchronized so to provide the proper access to its data you should syncronize it manually.
ThreadPool do both of theese internally.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a boolean in every PortListenTask that indicates whether it's still running, then while looping through the threads check that boolean and if necessary remove it from the list using remove(int index).
You can also make the list static, and remove the entry from the list from within the thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the newer version of Java (jdk 6), then look in to [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

In case you are constrained and want an alternative approach, try using observer-observable pattern. You can use ['events'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeEvent.html) to achieve the same.